# Pybrain validator functions

Tags: python, pybrain

I came across

```
ModuleValidator.MSE(net, trndata)
```

and

```
trainer.testOnData(dataset=trndata)
```

In the documentation, it says both function output the mean squared error. But when I implement it on my network, both output is not the same as opposed to the documentation.
Anyone knows better?

Answer (score 0):

You can build it from scratch using Python numpy functions:

```
    from numpy import mean, sqrt, square
    import random 
    l= [random.randint(0,1000) for r in xrange(10)]
    MSE = sqrt(mean(square(l)))
```

Or Use the one from [Scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

MSE = sqrt(mean_squared_error(x,y))
```

Comment: the functions I wrote above both output the MSE. i just dont understand why both output is different. Its suppose to be the same is it not?

Comment: @dnth; what is "net" in the first one. in the second function you are applying only on trndata.

Comment: im applying both function on trndata. 'net' is any pybrain network. in my case it is a recurrent net.

Comment: Just for the sake of experimentation, try to test the validator with sklearn.metric.mean_squared_error ? which function produce similar results ?